# Laravel 5.4 webpack compiling order

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Learning `webpack` and working on `Laravel 5.4`. I noticed in my `webpack.mix.js` that although the physical order of my chained commands is correct, the execution is not top down. As such, the `.script` command seems to run after the `.js` command. This means that any changes to these files needs `mix` to run twice, which also screws up the `watch` command.

Is there a way to force the order of execution and make the `.js` command run after the `.script` merge finishes?

```
mix
    .options({ processCssUrls: false })
    .scripts([
            'resources/assets/js/web/web.js',
            'resources/assets/js/web/web-login.js',
            'resources/assets/js/web/web-register.js',
            'resources/assets/js/common/helpers.js',
        ],
        'resources/assets/js/output/web.js'
    )
    .js('resources/assets/js/output/web.js', 'public/js/web.js' )
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/web/web.scss', 'public/css');
```